# How to redirect to swagger using Apache2 and ASP.Net Core 3.1?

Tags: apache, asp.net-core, swagger, apache2, swashbuckle

I'm working on my simple home project. I have a virtual Linux (Debian) server with apache 2 and working .Net Core app.

My setup:

- Static app in React store in `/var/www/html/`
- .Net Core app as a service

I've made that config and added it to `/etc/apache2/conf-available` (with symlink in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /api http://127.0.0.1:5000/api
    ProxyPassReverse /api http://127.0.0.1:5000/api
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/aspnetcore-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/aspnetcore-access.log common
</VirtualHost>


 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /swagger http://127.0.0.1:5000/swagger
    ProxyPassReverse /swagger http://127.0.0.1:5000/swagger
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/aspnetcore-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/aspnetcore-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Routing to `/api` works fine, but I cannot make that swagger works.

And here is my swagger config.

```cs
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
        c.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.None);
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Ghoulnite");

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        else
            c.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
        });
```

When I redirect to HTTP:/my-ip/swagger I get Apache not found site.

[image]

It's working locally, when I go using `lynx` to `http://127.0.0.1/swagger`

How can I redirect to swagger using Apache2 and ASP.Net Core 3.1?